# Proof that half of the subgroup is even

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $n$ be an even positive integer and let $\mathbb Z_n$ be the integers modulo $n$ with addition. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$.

I tried to show the following:

Either all of the elements in $H$ are even or exactly half of them.

My proof:

If all of them are even we are done. So assume there was one that was odd. Let $h \in H$ be odd. Since $h \neq 0$ the order of $h$ equals $|H|$ hence

$$ \langle h \rangle = \{h, 2h, \dots, 2kh\} = H$$

for some $k$ where we have used that $|H|$ is even.

Now the final step in my proof is:

Looking at the set $\{h, 2h, \dots, 2kh\}$ we see that we can "pair up" adjacent elements into pairs like $h, 2h$ which contain one even and one odd element. Hence exactly half of $H$ is even.

> Is there a more mathamtically rigorous way to finish the proof?

The argument "look at a set and then it's obvious" seems hand-wavy to me.  After all, "make pairs" is not mathematically rigorous.

Comment: @vadim123 He's not considering $\Bbb Z_7$; in the first sentence of the question, OP states that $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define a function $\Phi : H \longrightarrow K$ where $K$ is the multipicative group ${\{-1,1}\}$, such that $\Phi (x)=1$ if $x$ is even and $\Phi (x)=-1$ if $x$ is odd. Since $n$ is even, we can see that $\Phi$ is operation preserving, and thus, a homomorphism. $Ker(\Phi)$ is the subgroup of even numbers in $H$. By First Isomorphism Theorem, $H/Ker(\Phi) \cong \Phi(H)$. If $\Phi(H)={\{1,-1}\}$, then $H/Ker(\Phi)$ has two elements; the coset of even numbers, or $\Phi(H)$, and the coset of odd numbers; the two have equal cardinality, so half are even. Otherwise, $\Phi(H)={\{1}\}$, so all elements are even.

Comment: Very nice answer, I like that argument. Thank you!